# Partitioning a segment

Tags: geometry

1. A directed line segment from (-2,-2) to B it is divided by P(4,0) in a ratio 2:1. Where is B?

I just don't understand how to get the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you travel from $(-2,-2)$ to $(4,0)$, which covers a certain distance-what is it?  Now you keep going in a straight line half that far.  Where do you wind up?  One way is to parameterize the line as $(x,y)=(-2,-2)+t[(4,0)-(-2,-2)]$  What should you set $t$ to?

Comment: Or just use this process on the x-co-ordinate, then on the y.

Answer (score 0):

If a line segment has end point $(x_1,y_1)\;\; and\;\;(x_2,y_2)$ any point $P(x_3,y_3)$ divide it in $m:n$ then there is this relation:
$$x_3=\dfrac{m\cdot x_2+n\cdot x_1}{m+n}\;\;and\;\;y_3=\dfrac{m\cdot y_2+n\cdot y_1}{m+n}$$
[image]

so here:

$$4=\dfrac{2\cdot x_1+1\cdot (-2)}{2+1}\;\;and\;\;0=\dfrac{2\cdot y_1+1\cdot (-2)}{2+1}$$
$$x_1=7\;\;,y=1$$